# Disabling filling does not work with patches

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a triangular patch with no filling.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \node at (axis cs:0,0) {$1$};
            \addplot[patch,patch type=triangle,fill=none] coordinates {(0,0) [] (-1/sqrt(3),-1) (1/sqrt(3),-1)};
            \node at (axis cs:{-1/sqrt(3)},-1) {$x$};
            \node at (axis cs:{1/sqrt(3)},-1) {$y$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It does not work, the patch still has a color. How do I disable the filling for a patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the keyword `mesh` to the `\addplot` options to disable the filling.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \node at (axis cs:0,0) {$1$};
            \addplot[patch, mesh, patch type=triangle] coordinates {(0,0) [] (-1/sqrt(3),-1) (1/sqrt(3),-1)};
            \node at (axis cs:{-1/sqrt(3)},-1) {$x$};
            \node at (axis cs:{1/sqrt(3)},-1) {$y$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm ;).